# Python Geocoder call getting frozen after a certain number of executions

Tags: python, pickle, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api, geocode

I am working on a Python application, which uses the geocoder library to find the latitude and longitude information for a given address and store it in a Redis key. All the information is serialized and stored in a single Redis key and from there a NodeJS application reads this data and renders it to a Map.

Now, when I run the code, for some of the addresses, the geoinformation is not available and I store these values with the string `na` as the first element in the array. For all the addresses, which has correct geo info, the first element in the array is `true`.

I have another Python script, which checks whether the geo-information is available for these missing entries, and if it is there, it will update the Redis value with this info. So I have the following code:

```
latlonData = pickle.loads(r.get("latlon_all"))
        i = 0
        for orgid, row in latlonData.items():
            if latlonData[orgid][0] == "na":
                accuracy, latitude, longitude = self.getCoordinates(row[3])

                if latitude is not None:
                    latlonData[orgid] = [accuracy, latitude, longitude, latlonData[orgid][3], latlonData[orgid][4]]
                    print(latlonData[orgid])
                    i += 1
                    r.append('lat_lon_append', latlonData[orgid])

        r.set('latlon_all', pickle.dumps(latlonData))
```

and the `getCoordinates()` function is as follows:

```
import pickle
import geocoder

def getCoordinates(self, query):
    accuracy, latitude, longitude = 'na', None, None
    apiKey = 'MYAPIKEY'

    geoCodes = geocoder.google(query, key=apiKey)
    print(geoCodes.json)
    if geoCodes.json is not None:
        if geoCodes.json['status'] == 'OK':
            latitude = geoCodes.json['lat']
            longitude = geoCodes.json['lng']
            quality = geoCodes.json.get('quality', None)
            if quality:
                if geoCodes.json['quality'] == 'STREET':
                    accuracy = 'true'
                else:
                    accuracy = 'false'
            else:
                accuracy = 'false'
    else:
        pass
    return accuracy, latitude, longitude
```

I have a number of addresses (12000+), and almost for 4600, the geoinformation is missing. I loop through every address and check whether the `na` value is there and if it is so, calling Google GeoCode API to get the info. Now after some time, the code is getting frozen. I have printed the `i` value there and it is 2497 after this the code is completely frozen and is not showing any error. I have to kill the process manually to stop the execution.

I tried to run the script with a condition that checks the value for `i` and if it is more than 2496, then only it will query the geoinformation. But this is also getting frozen after some iteration. I am new to Python and not sure what is happening here. When I checked the limits, there are no maximum limits for the Google API, but there is a limit of 50 requests per second. I think my code is well under the limits, but have added a sleep for 2 seconds between the API calls. Still the script has the same behavior and it is frozen. It would be helpful if someone can check this code and advice me on a better way of doing this without getting stuck after a certain number of iternations

Adding the stack trace when I kill the code execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scripts/temp/geo_na_process_google.py", line 94, in <module>
    geoObj.process()
  File "/scripts/temp/geo_na_process_google.py", line 16, in process
    self.checkRecords()
  File "/scripts/temp/geo_na_process_google.py", line 25, in checkRecords
    accuracy, latitude, longitude = self.getCoordinates(row[3])
  File "/scripts/temp/geo_na_process_google.py", line 43, in getCoordinates
    geoCodes = geocoder.google(query, key=apiKey)
  File "Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/geocoder/api.py", line 232, in google
    return get(location, provider='google', **kwargs)
  File "Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/geocoder/api.py", line 198, in get
    return options[provider][method](location, **kwargs)
  File "Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/geocoder/base.py", line 410, in __init__
    self._initialize()
  File "Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/geocoder/base.py", line 457, in _initialize
    json_response = self._connect()
  File "Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/geocoder/base.py", line 479, in _connect
    self.response = response = self.rate_limited_get(
  File "Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/geocoder/google.py", line 269, in rate_limited_get
    return self.rate_limited_get_for_dev(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/ratelim/__init__.py", line 33, in wrapped_f
    time.sleep(self.__time_interval - time_delta + 1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: When the program freezes and you kill it, it should print the stack trace of the program. This tells you in which function you were stuck, which is already a first information. Is it `geocoder.google(query)` or somewhere else in your code ?

Comment: @BigBro Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question with the stack trace. It is the geocoder call that is failing. I think this is something related to the rate limit as I have used a new API key and still, it is failing around 2600. If there is a limit, what is the possible way to overcome this other than executing the script over multiple days?

Comment: Indeed the stack shows a call to `rate_limited_get`. You might be able to change your billing option to avoid it. You can also retry the request in the code when too much time has elapsed, to see if a new request will succeed. Is it a one time thing or do you need to repeat the operation every day ?

Comment: When I checked the Google Maps console, the maximum rate limit for a day is 3000. Not sure this can be increased further. This is a one-time script and no need to repeat it on a daily basis.

Comment: It's a bit strange indeed. I'd implement a function to call `geocoding` with a timeout and retry the request when it times out, after an appropriate sleep. This way you're sure the script will finish, even if it takes a day to do so